# gmake can't find generated sources

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a program that some of its sources are generated. the relevant part of the makefile is something like this:

```
OUTPUT_FILE = libEngine.so
CONF_FILES = foo.tgp bar.tgp
GENERATED = Engine.cfg
SRCS = main.cpp foo.cpp bar.cpp 
OBJ_FILES = $(SRCS:%.cpp=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)

all: $(OUTPUT_FILE)

$(OUTPUT_FILE): $(GENERATED) $(OBJ_FILES)
   <link command>

$(GENERATED): $(CONF_FILES)
   generate -p Engine $(CONF_FILES)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o:%.cpp
   <compile command>
```

'generate' command creates Engine.cfg (a text file), foo.cpp and bar.cpp

When I run it, on *some* platforms, *sometimes*, gmake stops after generating and compiling the non-generated, saying that it has no rule for creating the objects from the generated sources.

I think I know what the problem is - gmake evaluated the dependencies before the files were created. However, I don't see how to write it correctly. And I also don't understand why it only fails sometimes.

**Edit** example code is more complete now. (the original has much more files and options, of course)

Comment: So where and how does the variable `GENERATED` get its value?

Comment: something like:
GENERATED = table.cfg
GENERATED_SRCS = gen1.cpp gen2.cpp

Comment: Wait... which of these rules fails to run? And could you give us a minimal complete example?

Comment: hmmm... I'm not sure which is the failed rule. After running gmake, I have foo.cpp bar.cpp and main.o, and it says it has no rule to create foo.o

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, and it was related to VPATH. The cpp files are not generated in the current directory, but in another one, somewhere in an included makefile it is defined. I guess VPATH locations don't work if the file doesn't exists.

I fixed it this way:

```
all: $(GENERATED) $(OBJ_FILES)
     $(MAKE) $(OUTPUT_FILE)

$(OUTPUT_FILE): $(GENERATED) $(OBJ_FILES)
    <link command>
```

And so far so good.